# How do you fix a FileNotFound error code even though the directory does exist on the drive?

Tags: python, path

My teacher told our class to make a basic image classifier and I am running into trouble with properly trying to cite a path to the directory even though the directory exists on the hard drive.

I tried renaming the directory and even copied the path directly from Properties in order to ensure I was not citing the directory wrong.

```
import os
import cv2 

DATADIR = "D:\Datasets\PetImages"
CATEGORIES = ['Cat, Dog']

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

Even though I think I properly cited the directory, I still get the following  error code.

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'D:\\Datasets\\PetImages\\Cat, Dog'
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `tensorflow` or `neural-network` - kindly do not spam the tags (removed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, I made typo in the previous answer.
try this:

```
import os
import cv2 

DATADIR = "D:\Datasets\PetImages"
CATEGORIES = ['Cat', 'Dog']

for category in CATEGORIES:
    path = os.path.join(DATADIR, category)
    for img in os.listdir(path):
        img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img), cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

You forgot to separate cat and dog category, so unless you have this file 'D:\Datasets\PetImages\Cat, Dog',  it will not be able to find any files for that directory.

Comment: Your response fixed my problem. Thank you so much for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

Change: `CATEGORIES = ['Cat, Dog']` to `CATEGORIES = ['Cat', 'Dog']`

Comment: Your response fixed my problem. Thank you so much for the help!!